# Getting seconds until the start of the next hour?

Tags: php

I'm writing a small API call which returns the current amount of seconds left until the end of the hour, the end of the day, and the end of the week.

Getting the end of day/week was easy, in just using `strtotime('tomorrow')` or `strtotime('next sunday')` and subtracting with `time()`. However, I'm not seeing any available function that would allow me to get the timestamp of the start of the next hour.

`strtime('next hour')` just returns back the current timestamp +1 hour - rather than the time remaining until the next hour starts.

Is there any simple way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Using Datetime  is a better option IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use strtotime you can do this

```
 $start=date("H:i:s");
 $end=date("H:00:00",strtotime("$start +1 hour"));
 $secondsleft = (strtotime($end) - strtotime($start));
```

Comment: This works for hours/days, but gets a bit more complicated with weeks.

Comment: Agreed, just kept my answer specific to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I'd encourage you to consider the [Carbon date library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for this sort of math. It makes things quite trivial:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfHour()->diffInSeconds(Carbon\Carbon::now())
Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->diffInSeconds(Carbon\Carbon::now())
Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->diffInSeconds(Carbon\Carbon::now())
```

Comment: Installing and learning a whole library seems a bit extra for the simple request of the OP.

Comment: IMO, Carbon should be a standard part of pretty much any PHP app that has to work with dates. Laravel, for example, bundles it in a default install. In the days of Composer, avoiding libraries just because they're libraries doesn't make much sense.